# Prove that $\gcd(2^{2^m}+1,2^{2^n}+1)=1$ if $m,n$ are positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $\gcd(2^{2^m}+1,2^{2^n}+1)=1$ if $m,n$ are positive integers.

Let $d=\gcd(2^{2^m}+1,2^{2^n}+1)$, then $d\mid 2^{2^m}+1$ and $d\mid2^{2^n}+1$ and then $d\mid2^{2^m}+1-2^{2^n}-1$, i.e. $d\mid2^{2^m}-2^{2^n}$ where we have taken $m>n$. Thus $d\mid2^{2^n}(2^{2^{m-n}}-1)$, but $d \nmid 2^{2^n}$ thus $d\mid2^{2^{m-n}}-1$.

Then how will I proceed??

Comment: Note proper use of \gcd, \mid, and \nmid in my edits to the question.  The expression $a|b$, coded by a|b, lacks proper spacing, but $a\mid b$, coded by a\mid b, looks different.  Similarly \gcd not only prevents italicization, but also results in proper spacing in things like $a\gcd(b,c)$ (between $a$ and $\gcd$). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Your arithmetic is a little off: $$\large2^{2^m}-2^{2^n} =2^{2^n}\left(2^{2^m-2^n}-1\right) =2^{2^n}\left(2^{2^n\left(2^{m-n}-1\right)}-1\right)\;.$$

Comment: See also https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat_Numbers_are_Coprime

Comment: Not to be a jerk about it, but $m \neq n$, right?

Answer (score 8):

Let $a_n = 2^{2^n}+1$. Then:

$$ a_{n+m} = (a_n-1)^{2^m}+1, $$
hence:
$$ a_{n+m}\equiv (-1)^{2^m}+1 = 2\pmod{a_n}, $$
from which it follows that:
$$ \gcd(a_{n+m},a_{n}) = \gcd(2,a_n)=1 $$
since $a_n$ is odd.

Comment: I like this a little better than the method shown on wikipedia, which first requires using induction to prove that for $n\geq 2$,  $$F_n = \prod_{k<m}F_k + 2$$ That makes their proof longer and less direct.

Comment: @MarkFischler: thank you, I appreciate that. Truth to be told, such identity is not that painful to prove, since $F_n-2$ is a telescopic product due to $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$.

Comment: Wonderful answer @JackD'Aurizio, using the same approach leads gcd of $(a^{2^n}+1,a^{2^m}+1)$ for general a.

Answer (score 0):

${\bf Hint}\rm\quad\ \ \gcd(a\!+\!1,\,\ a^{\large 2K}\!+1)\ =\ gcd(a\!+\!1,\,\color{#0a0}2)\,$  by Euclid's gcd algorithm.

${\bf Proof}\rm\ \ \ mod\ a\!+\!1\!:\,\  \color{#c00}a^{\large 2K}\!+1\: \equiv\ (\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 2K}\!+1\:\equiv\ \color{#0a0}2,\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{a\equiv -1,}\, \ {\rm by}\, \ a\!+\!1\equiv 0$

OP is case  $\rm\,\ a=2^{\Large 2^{M}}\!\!,\ \ 2K = 2^{\large N-M} \Rightarrow\ a^{\large 2K}\! = 2^{\Large 2^{N}}\!,\ $  wlog $\rm\ N>M.$

**Remark** $\rm\ \gcd(a\!+\!1,f(a))\, =\, \gcd(a\!+\!1,f(-1))\,$ for *any* polynomial $\rm\,f(x)\,$ with integer coefficients, with proof exactly as above, except generally we need to use the  [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879251/divisibility-for-7/879262#879262) vs. the Power or Product Rules.